# Joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

```
Table 1                              
ID  MONTH1  NUM NUM2
XO3     4   0
XO1 DEC 1   1
XO1 JAN 1   2
XO2 DEC 3   3
XO2 JAN 3   4

Table 2
ID  MONTH1  NUM
XO3     
XO1 DEC 
XO1 JAN 
XO2 JAN
```

1>

```
UPDATE Table1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON Table1.ID = TABLE2.ID 
SET TABLE2.NUM = [Table1].[NUM]
WHERE (((TABLE2.MONTH1)=Table1.MONTH1) And ((TABLE2.ID)=Table1.ID));
```

2>

```
UPDATE Table2 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON (Table2.MONTH1 = Table1.MONTH1) AND (Table2.ID = Table1.ID) 
SET Table2.NUM = [Table1].[NUM];
```

3>

```
Now 
Table 2 shows 
ID  MONTH1  NUM
XO3     
XO1 DEC 1
XO1 JAN 1
XO2 JAN 3
```

So my question is what is the difference between 1> and 2> queries as either of the both the queries are giving me 3> , if i run 1> query  then i get 3> as answer because table shows the updated column NUM as 1,2,3 or
if I run the second query 2> it again shows the updated column NUM as 1,2,3

Please tell me the difference thank u.

Comment: Please tag properly.  Is this SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

The query are  equivalent  .. the difference is only in the aspect of the join condition

in the first the join condition is in part in on clause and and the rest in where

```
  ON Table1.ID = TABLE2.ID 
  WHERE (((TABLE2.MONTH1)=Table1.MONTH1) And ((TABLE2.ID)=Table1.ID));
```

in the second the join is only in on clause

```
   ON (Table2.MONTH1 = Table1.MONTH1) AND (Table2.ID = Table1.ID)
```

then they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes both query yield same result then what is difference? right let's see

1. Query

   ```
   UPDATE Table1 
   INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON Table1.ID = TABLE2.ID 
   SET TABLE2.NUM = [Table1].[NUM]
   WHERE (((TABLE2.MONTH1)=Table1.MONTH1) And ((TABLE2.ID)=Table1.ID));
   ```

In this query you are fetching all matching the records (`Table1.ID = TABLE2.ID`) from both table, then you applying filtering criteria like this
`WHERE (((TABLE2.MONTH1)=Table1.MONTH1) And ((TABLE2.ID)=Table1.ID))` and then perform update operation on final result.

2. Query

   ```
   UPDATE Table2 
   INNER JOIN Table1 ON (Table2.MONTH1 = Table1.MONTH1) AND (Table2.ID = Table1.ID) 
   SET Table2.NUM = [Table1].[NUM];
   ```

In this query you are fetching matching records with matching criteria like `(Table2.MONTH1 = Table1.MONTH1) AND (Table2.ID = Table1.ID)`

so  this make more efficient while fetching records since no extra efforts required again for filtering records so results in gaining better performance.